# Getting Datatable Error in WordPress/WooCommerce/WCFM Multi Vendor Plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to add this code into WCFM (WordPress & WooCommerce hooks) but I got Datatables error after I update it. Sorry, I'm a newbie. Is it my code below that was right?

```
add_filter( 'wcfm_orders_additonal_data_hidden', '__return_false' );
add_filter('wcfm_orders_additonal_data',function($order,$order_id)
 { 
           
          // Custom Integrations
           
           $ep_order_id = $order->order_id;
           $ep_product_id = str_replace(",", "-", $order->product_id);

            $ep_check_order_make = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ep_courier_order WHERE order_id = ".$order->order_id." AND vendor_id = ".$this->vendor_id );

            if(empty($ep_check_order_make[0]->ep_service_id)){
                $wcfm_orders_json_arr[$index][] = "Service id Null";
            }else{

                if(empty($ep_check_order_make[0]->ep_order_number)){

                    $wcfm_orders_json_arr[$index][] = '<button type="button" id="'.$ep_order_id.'" onclick="ep_making_order('.$ep_order_id.',\''.$ep_product_id.'\','.$this->vendor_id.',\''.$gross_sales_amt.'\')">Ready to pack</button>';
                }else{

                    $ep_order_number = $ep_check_order_make[0]->ep_order_number;
                    $ep_message = $ep_check_order_make[0]->ep_message;
                    $ep_awb = $ep_check_order_make[0]->ep_awb;
                    $ep_awb_id_link = $ep_check_order_make[0]->ep_awb_id_link;
                    $ep_tracking_url = $ep_check_order_make[0]->ep_tracking_url;

                    if(!empty($ep_awb_id_link)){
                        $wcfm_orders_json_arr[$index][] = $ep_check_order_make[0]->ep_courier."<br><a href='".$ep_awb_id_link."' target='_blank' style='color:blue'>AWB</a><br><a href='".$ep_tracking_url."' target='_blank' style='color:green'>Tracking No: ".$ep_check_order_make[0]->ep_awb."</a>";
                    }else{
                        $wcfm_orders_json_arr[$index][] = '<button type="button" id="'.$ep_order_number.'" onclick="ep_making_order_payment(\''.$ep_order_number.'\','.$ep_order_id.')">Ready to ship</button><br>'.$ep_message;
                    }
                }

            }
           
           $wcfm_orders_json_arr[$index][] = "For Vendor Only";// End of Integrations

       return $order; },10,2); 
add_filter('wcfm_orders_additional_info_column_label',function($lbl){ return 'Ship'; },10);
```

Comment: Please provide a text of error message

Comment: Issue solved! Thanks